# nftables deleting a rule without passing handle (similar to iptables delete)

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, nftables, netfilter

iptables syntax for delete is much simpler. if we replace the "append" with delete we get command for deletion of the rule.

nftable provides similar construct for few rule management aspect such as

1. add a table and delete a table (symmetric add and delete)
2. add a chain and delete a chain (symmetric add and delete)

My query is

1. Is there any reason/rationale for not providing same for adding a rule and deleting a rule?
2. is there any more convenient way to delete a rule (other than grab handle and use handle to delete a rule

Many thanks

Comment: Answering part 2. would be easier if you provided an example letting you think you need this unavailable feature.

Answer (score 0):

One rationale I can think about is about having the same cost when deleting a rule as when adding a rule.

With *iptables* (legacy) this was also the same cost for the wrong reasons: adding or deleting a *single* rule forced to transmit the *whole* ruleset from kernel, edit it in userland (the *iptables* command) and put back again the whole ruleset in kernel. So adding one rule to a ruleset with 1000000 rules required processing 1000000+1 rules anyway. *iptables-nft*, while using the *nftables* kernel API as backend, has no choice but to be compatible so will have to retrieve more than needed when asked to delete a rule and do userland work.

With *nftables*, when adding a rule, only this single rule is sent to kernel which will then send back its handle (but using an index will probably require extra work). Adding 1 rule to a chain with 1000000 rules has no extra cost related to these 1000000 rules already present. To delete a rule by content would require to retrieve at least the whole chain and parse it until found, possibly having to parse 1000000 rules. While parsing is fine for display, this should be avoided whenever possible when performing operations that need to be fast. Having an unique handle is faster. I guess the decision was made to avoid this runtime cost at the cost of management methods.

Now depending on the problem there are multiple ways to not have to rely on deletion *by content*.

- Separate data from code (to be preferred)

  Using named [*sets*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets), [*maps*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Maps) and [*vmaps*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Verdict_Maps_(vmaps)) allows to keep static rules that will use dynamic data: then there's no need to add or delete rules in typical runtime use, but instead only to add or delete *elements*. *element* lookup (during packet path traversal) and manipulation (during setup or dynamic use (eg: a tool blacklisting addresses in real-time such as [fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/1.0.2/config/action.d/nftables.conf#L119)) ) are optimized for this use (with proper hashing etc. under the hood) and manipulation is not done by handle but by content.

  Likewise, *iptables* can leverage *ipset* for the same purpose, but *nftables* being more generic usually allows more interaction with these data structures than is possible with *iptables* and *ipset*.
- Store (during program or script execution) the handle immediately after it was created.

  `nft --echo --handle ...` will echo back then rule with its handle whenever added. With also `--json` for JSON output it can be easier to do something automated with it. The tool can then do what *iptables* was also doing in userland: find a matching rule to figure out the handle, but probably in an easier way since this would be a tailored use.
- Split rules into specific regular (user) chains

  Just as is possible with *iptables*, use dedicated chains whose role is to have data rather than code. Then to rebuild them, flush them first and populate them back from an external source of data. As *nftables* operations can be atomic (when using `nft -f ...`) there is no temporary misbehaving ruleset to be expected.

  Still it would be preferable to use a *set*/*map*/*vmap* instead: A packet will traverse linearly a chain with all its rules so traversing a chain having n rules attempting to match this packet has an average lookup time of O(n), while a *set*/*map*/*vmap* (called from a single rule) is hashed and gets a faster traversal: an average lookup time of O(1).